List of kanji with unexpected stroke order?
I was going to call this question "kanji with unconventional or non-standard stroke order," but I guess stroke order is established by convention, and whatever has become the convention is the standard.
What I'm interested in is a list of kanji where the stroke order diverges from what one might expect given the basic top-to-bottom, left-to-right rule, and which you just have to learn by rote.
Here are some examples where the basic rules wouldn't help you work out the order...
The famous 右 and 左:


And 力 and 九:


I realized this was an issue after assuming an order for a given character, only to find out later that it wasn't what I had expected.
It'd be great if such a list of "problem" kanji also tried to justify or explain the unexpected order, e.g. for 右 and 左, it seems to come down to the basic top-bottom etc. rule not being quite enough (see this answer). So, this makes me think there are maybe more rules to be learned that would help avoid surprise at the order in the first place.

The answer below mine by Ignacio in the linked question explains a more historical reason about 右 and 左.
